# IdeaIC inspect cli failed with '-changes' options

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

I try to use ideaIC inspect cli to check local uncommitted changes in Ubuntu.

According to [website docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-code-inspector.html), whole project code inspections had been execed successfull with command `bin/inspect.sh $(pwd) $(pwd)/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml temp -v2`.

But when I try to use `-changes` option like `bin/inspect.sh $(pwd) $(pwd)/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml temp -changes -v2` , unexpected error occurred. I found the error message in [code](https://github.com/luckystar5408/Jvav-Studio-Community/blob/c82a376cfca4ad0c18c25cfd691fbf11f97a6f50/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/projectRoots/impl/UnknownSdkInspectionCommandLineConfigurator.kt#L19), but I can't found any solution about it.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Starting up IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3 (build IC-202.7660.26) ...done.
Opening project...2021-02-26 16:41:48,634 [   1629]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.alibaba.p3c.idea.component.AliProjectComponent) 
2021-02-26 16:41:49,018 [   2013]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=org.jetbrains.android.compose.AndroidComposeAutoDocumentation) 
Feb 26, 2021 4:41:49 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleSetNode
WARNING: RuleSet description is missing. Future versions of PMD will require it.
Feb 26, 2021 4:41:50 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RuleSetFactory parseRuleSetNode
WARNING: RuleSet description is missing. Future versions of PMD will require it.
2021-02-26 16:41:50,181 [   3176]   WARN - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Activities registered via registerPostStartupActivity must be dumb-aware: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.ui.KotlinConfigurationCheckerComponent$projectOpened$1@48ae78 
done.
Initializing project...Loaded profile 'Project Default' from file '/home/user/workspace/lab/mai/bigdata/home/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml'
modified file/home/user/workspace/lab/mai/bigdata/home/src/main/java/com/maiscrm/bigdata/spark/app/etl/CommonIncrementalCollectionLoader.java
done.
Inspecting with profile 'Project Default'
Running first analysis stage...

Shelving changes...
2021-02-26 16:41:55,220 [   8215]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Heap Dump Analysis' is already registered in whitelist 
2021-02-26 16:41:55,220 [   8215]   WARN - ion.impl.NotificationCollector - Notification group 'Low Memory' is already registered in whitelist 
Running second analysis stage...

2021-02-26 16:41:55,370 [   8365]  ERROR - spection.InspectionApplication - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The code below uses the same GUI thread to complete operations.Running from EDT would deadlock 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The code below uses the same GUI thread to complete operations.Running from EDT would deadlock
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ex.ApplicationUtil.invokeAndWaitSomewhere(ApplicationUtil.java:160)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressInCurrentThread(CoreProgressManager.java:535)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:335)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.CallbackData.lambda$createInteractive$3(CallbackData.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.UpdateRequestsQueue.invokeAfterUpdate(UpdateRequestsQueue.java:177)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl.invokeAfterUpdate(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl.invokeAfterUpdate(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:344)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.run(InspectionApplication.java:235)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.execute(InspectionApplication.java:140)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.startup(InspectionApplication.java:107)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionMain.main(InspectionMain.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ApplicationStarter.main(ApplicationStarter.java:62)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$8.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:231)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:783)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$nonEdtExecutor$1.execute(ApplicationLoader.kt:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompletion.claim(CompletableFuture.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1069)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1742)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:26)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:186)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The code below uses the same GUI thread to complete operations.Running from EDT would deadlock
    at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.UnknownSdkInspectionCommandLineConfigurator$configureProject$1.invokeSuspend(UnknownSdkInspectionCommandLineConfigurator.kt:38)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:272)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:79)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:54)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:36)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.projectRoots.impl.UnknownSdkInspectionCommandLineConfigurator.configureProject(UnknownSdkInspectionCommandLineConfigurator.kt:37)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.configureProject(InspectionApplication.java:350)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.lambda$runUnderProgress$21(InspectionApplication.java:574)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.runUnderProgress(InspectionApplication.java:573)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.runAnalysis(InspectionApplication.java:373)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.runAnalysisOnScope(InspectionApplication.java:343)
    at com.intellij.codeInspection.InspectionApplication.lambda$run$4(InspectionApplication.java:241)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.Waiter.onSuccess(Waiter.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.finishTask(CoreProgressManager.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressInCurrentThread$9(CoreProgressManager.java:535)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeAndWait$8(ApplicationImpl.java:475)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:132)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:188)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:499)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-02-26 16:41:55,372 [   8367]  ERROR - spection.InspectionApplication - IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3  Build #IC-202.7660.26 
2021-02-26 16:41:55,372 [   8367]  ERROR - spection.InspectionApplication - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2021-02-26 16:41:55,372 [   8367]  ERROR - spection.InspectionApplication - OS: Linux 
2021-02-26 16:41:55,372 [   8367]  ERROR - spection.InspectionApplication - Last Action:  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The code below uses the same GUI thread to complete operations.Running from EDT would deadlock
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved in 2020.3.2 version of IntelliJ IDEA. Related issue in JB bugtracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-263195